# 'Failed with: TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined' when running Parse background job

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Whenever I run my Parse background job, it fails and I get the error below:

```
Failed with: TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
        at Object.b.Query._quote (Parse.js:3:14236)
        at Object.b.Query.contains (Parse.js:3:14337)
        at main.js:1488:40
```

This is the area causing the problem, line 1488 is the 2nd line:

```
  var MCI_Results_Update_Query = new Parse.Query(MCI_Results);
  MCI_Results_Update_Query.contains('searchTerm', searchTermList[i]);
  MCI_Results_Update_Query.equalTo('parent', parentUser);
```

All I'm doing here is setting the parameters for a query, there's no `replace` method involved at all. What's causing it to state that as the error? I triple checked, and I'm almost positive this is the line  it's referring to.

Comment: Try checking the parameters you are passing. Though obvious this error comes if method is called on null/undefined object. Like `var d; d.replace(/a/ig,'b');` will throw same error.

Comment: You should make sure both `searchTerm` and `serchTermList[i]` do exist.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot @eth3lbert I console.log'd `searchTermList[i]` and it does indeed exist. I made a similar query a few lines earlier using it and it worked, no idea why it doesn't work here.